# SocialEngine addon's Core Plugin

Tags: macos, socialengine

While uploading the socialengine addon's core plugin (module-seaocore-4.6.0p5.tar) through package manager, I am getting an error

Unable to move file to packages directory. 
Please set chmod 0777 on the temporary/package/archives directory.

But, if we try to upload any other plugin, it will get extracted in the normal way.

I have checked the file permission and it is already 0777.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this,

Extract the ".tar file" and then open the "applications" folder and you will find 3 folder "languages, modules, packages" copy all the files and folders you find in these folders and paste them to the respective "application" folder in your working directory,

**remember**

After copying them again give the chmod - R 0777 permission to you package directory of working folder.

sudo chmod -R 0777 packages/

Now you can find an option to install the plugin in "Manage Plugin" section in the admin pannel.